# Send data to different websocket endpoints in one connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, frontend

i have a question about websockets and sending data to different backend-endpoints in Javascript.

So is it possible to send data to different backend-endpoints in one websocket connection or do i need to establish a new connection for every endpoint?

Lets say:

```
var ws = new Websocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// send data to /login
ws.send('/login', {logindata...});

// send data to /messages
ws.send('/messages', {data...});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you must do is define a message protocol so the server execute the correct endpoint for each type of message.

For example:

```
{
   "msgType": "login",
   "msgData": {logindata...}
}
```

and

```
{
   "msgType": "messages",
   "msgData": {data...}
}
```

Those could be you two type of messages you send to the server. And in the backend, have a controller to execute de "login/" endpoint or the "messages/" endpoint.

I don't know if that helps... That's the way I do it.

Comment: so there is no way to send it directly to the endpoint? I need a controller that handles the routing in the backend?

Comment: I can't say for sure... but in my experience, for the way that a websocket server works (at least the python one I've implemented)... I don't think so. Every message arrives at the same method in the server, the one that implements the "onMessage" event... Maybe there is some websocket server that allow you to define different "endpoints" like a web server does. I assume that a web server receive all messages through the same entrance, but implements it's own controller giving the developer the functionality to define different "routes" or "endpoints"...

Comment: ok. thanks for your comment. your solution is good an i will use it. i cannot upvote your answer but you will get the green hook :)